# Yup: Migrating when to 1.0.2

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, yup

Given a React state variable

```
const [selectedFormtype, setSelectedFormtype] = useState<Nullable<MyFormTypeVm>>()
```

Types/interfaces are defined like this

```
type Nullable<T> = T | null

interface MyFormTypeVm {
    readonly id: NonNullable<string>
    readonly labelCompanyId: Nullable<string>
}

interface MyFormVm {
    companyId: Nullable<string>
    // remaining properties goes here
}
```

I have this working solution with yup:0.32.11.

```
const validationSchema: yup.SchemaOf<MyFormVm> = yup.object().shape({
    companyId: yup.string().when([], {
        is: () => selectedFormtype?.labelCompanyId,
        then: yup.string()
            .required('Company-id is required')
            .matches(/^[8|9]\d{8}$/i, 'Company-id has to start with 8 or 9')
    })
).required()
```

I can see from [here](https://github.com/jquense/yup/pull/1542) how to implement a `when` that refers to another field in the validation scope

```
 string()
-   .when('other', function (other) => {
-      if (other) return this.required()
+   .when('other', ([other], schema) => {
+     return other ? schema.required() : schema
  })
```

The outline for my validationSchema should look like this according to the migration guide, but it gives me a TS2322-error.

```
const validationSchema: yup.ObjectSchema<MyFormVm> = yup.object().shape({
        companyId: yup.string().when('other', ([], schema) => {
            return selectedFormtype?.labelCompanyId
                ? schema
                      .required('required text goes here')
                      .matches(/^[8|9]\d{8}$/i, 'regex text goes here')
                : schema
        })
})
```

I've added the following to tsconfig.json:

"strictNullChecks": true,
"strictFunctionTypes": false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the way through this in the docs. `.default<Nullable<string>>(null)` solved casting from `string | null | undefined` to `string | null`.

```
const validationSchema: yup.ObjectSchema<MyFormVm> = yup.object().shape({
    companyId: yup.string().default<Nullable<string>>(null).when(([], schema) =>
        selectedFormtype?.labelCompanyId
            ? schema
                .required('required msg goes here')
                .matches(/^[8|9]\d{8}$/i, 'regex msg goes here')
            : schema.nullable()
    )
})
```